# Using Python how do I check a website is accessible or not

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a bunch of URLs of websites. Some of these URLs are no longer accessible as the website maybe deleted or for some other reasons. Could you help me how I can find it out.. I have tried the following code:

```
def url_ok(url):
    try:
        r = requests.head(url)
        return r.status_code
    except: 
        print("Status: False")
```

I was expecting that if an error occures while executing the script it probably means that the website doesnot exist anymore..
But to my surprise some of the urls flagged "false" due to the exception were actually accessible when i tried to access them manually using the browser.
So i guess my code doesnot work..
Could you guys help me how to find out that the urls are accessible or not using python?
I am using the urls in the Column "Websites" in this spreadsheet: [URls](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vMv6PG_GtER0g8ir1773R6imSnDnwJ58P_BjNl-sFcw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you provide a list of the URLs you are trying to use?

Comment: sure i can, just a min

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vMv6PG_GtER0g8ir1773R6imSnDnwJ58P_BjNl-sFcw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am using the urls in the column "websites"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [requests](https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_requests.asp) module and do a `GET` call to check response as `200`. Like this maybe:

```
In [292]: response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059821/using-python-how-do-i-check-a-website-is-accessible-or-not')
```

#### Updated answer after OP's comment:

In order to seem like the request is from browser you can do the following:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

In [296]: response.status_code                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[296]: 200
```

Just loop around your list of URL's and check whether the response is 200 or not.

```
for url in urls_list:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('{} is active'.format(url))
```

Comment: one of the url generated 403, but when i tried manually the website was accessible

Comment: It could be a case where website doesn't like traffic from "non-browsers", so they try to block such traffic. Hence 403.

Comment: Is there any way to get away with it?

Comment: I am using the urls in the column "Websites" of this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vMv6PG_GtER0g8ir1773R6imSnDnwJ58P_BjNl-sFcw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So are you asking, how to read "Websites" column from csv and process each request?

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) are divided in five classes, thus I suggest simply flagging all urls which produce `status_code < 400` as OK.
Edit: request' response has ok, working exactly this way, per its help:

```
 |  ok
 |      Returns True if :attr:`status_code` is less than 400, False if not.
 |
 |      This attribute checks if the status code of the response is between
 |      400 and 600 to see if there was a client error or a server error. If
 |      the status code is between 200 and 400, this will return True. This
 |      is **not** a check to see if the response code is ``200 OK``.
```

So you might just do:

```
import requests
r = requests.head('http://www.example.com')
print(r.ok)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: one of the url generated 403, but when i tried manually the website was accessible

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar: it might be blocking `requests` based on user-agent, some site does that for calls which does not look like made by web browser, to avoid excessive exploitation by automated scrapers.

Comment: is there any way to do it using selenium? as selenium uses browser to make requests

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar: while Selenium will work in this case, I suggest firstly to try using requests provided with browser-like user-agent. User-agent might be easily provided for `requests.get` (and other HTTP verbs) see: https://edmundmartin.com/random-user-agent-requests-python/ so I think it is worth giving a try before using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what's been said about `requests`, make sure your get requests are called with `allow_redirects=True`.

Comment: Hello i tried the methods @Maynak mentioned, but one of the url generated 403, but when i tried manually the website was accessible